# Best practice for maintaining dev Azure Active Directory (AAD) that closely mirrors production AAD?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I would like for our team to do all development work in a dev AAD that is configured very closely to the production AAD. In this manner, our work will not need to be changed to work in production.

Right now our team has:

- a production AAD tenant that has:

  - a production subscription
  - a development subscription; and,
- a test AAD tenant that is very simple and configured very differently from the prod tenant.

The utopia for me is that a true development environment where production security policy need not apply, but still be confident that what works in dev will also work in production. Can AAD be maintained programmatically and take advantage of CI/CD?

Comment: Is the prod setup currently completely automated? Ie. if disaster struck tomorrow, could you redeploy the tenant with the click of a button? If not, that's where I'd start :) Once you have the entire infra defined like this (codified using Terraform/ARM/whatever cloud formation tooling you prefer), deploying test systems becomes much easier - just change the template parameters and click the button again

Comment: do you examples of this?  how can you redeploy things like AAD if they don't have ARM templates?

Comment: Currently, this is not possible (3rd party tools might be available), you can, however, try to retrieve non-user specific settings via MS graph and use them as a template. Also, you may request for this feature or support similar ones here : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/33860326-backup-azure-active-directory

Comment: @Nishant-MSFTIdentity, thanks! I'm going to take your comment here and make it an answer (unless you'd like to do so yourself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Nishant - MSFT Identity's comment above...

> Currently, this is not possible (3rd party tools might be available), you can, however, try to retrieve non-user specific settings via MS graph and use them as a template. Also, you may request for this feature or support similar ones on [Azure Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/33860326-backup-azure-active-directory)